# Bootstrap grid system columns clarification

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-system

I'm still starting to learn Bootstrap and I'm puzzled by the grid system. The description of the grid system says

> Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to **12 columns** as the device or viewport size increases.

But how come in the succeeding examples, they show it like this?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

I know that xs is extra small devices and md is for medium device but how come the classes for xs are "col-xs-12" and "col-xs-6"? I mean, they now add up to 18 columns in contrast to the definition of the Bootstrap Grid System. Can someone please enlighten me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting it wrong. in extra small devices the first `div` will fill the whole row and the second one will be placed below it containing only `half` of the row because of the `col-xs-12` class.
If the sum of integers in bootstrap grid system is larger than 12, the column that is making the grid system more than 18 will be placed on the following row.

Explain by code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-8"></div>
</div>
```

in this case the two `.col-xs` elements will stick together because `4+8 = 12` and the `.row` will only contain 12 columns.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-8"></div>
</div>
```

Now the `.col-xs-5` column will be on the first row and `.col-xs-8` will fall into second row.

### For more clarification see the below image:

[image]

Comment: Just further clarifications sir on the second example you've given:
1. So it will now show two rows?
2. If yes, in the first row, the remaining 7 columns will be blank?
3. And in the second row, the remaining 4 columns will be blank too?

Comment: 1. it will show columns vertically following each other in a single `.row`.
2. yes it will remain blank.
3. yes that will remain blank too.

Answer (score 0):

xs & md set their fix size so, in lg(big sceen), you can use col-xs-12 col-xs-6 it will be set as its size. so, This is wrong :"they now add up to 18 columns in contrast to the definition of the Bootstrap Grid System."

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
```